# Installing Sage and Anaconda on macOS

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, sage

I've installed Anaconda but cannot install Sage through Anaconda. I tried this as recommended [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/sage):

`conda install -c conda-forge sage`

It worked overnight, created a large error report, and gave up. So can I just install the [DMG](https://github.com/3-manifolds/Sage_macOS/releases)? Isn't the resulting Sage application self-contained? If not, what do I do? I just want to make sure the Sage installation doesn't step on Python or anything else in Anaconda.

My setup is a Mac mini M1 running macOS Monterey 12.4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should certainly just be able to install the `dmg` file (the `arm` one for your architecture, I think) rather than go through `conda`. If you want to try `conda` again, Sage's "official" directions are here: https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/installation/conda.html#sec-installation-conda

Sage's installation is self-contained, so its Python, for example, should not interfere with anything else on your system.

Comment: Great! By the way, you may get a quick response to Sage questions more reliably if you ask on https://ask.sagemath.org/ or the sage-support Google group.